# wrong input tensor type in tensorflow lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert a model created from a DNNClassifier premade estimator in tensorflow 2.x in tflite.
i had trained the model and saved in a .pb file. 
when i try to convert in tflite i get this information:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Utente\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py:1276: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from from_estimator/modello1\variables\variables
INFO:tensorflow:The given SavedModel MetaGraphDef contains SignatureDefs with the following keys: {'classification', 'serving_default', 'predict'}
INFO:tensorflow:input tensors info: 
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: inputs
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: input_example_tensor:0, shape: (-1), type: DT_STRING
INFO:tensorflow:output tensors info: 
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: classes
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: dnn/head/Tile:0, shape: (-1, 4), type: DT_STRING
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: scores
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0, shape: (-1, 4), type: DT_FLOAT
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from from_estimator/modello1\variables\variables
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Utente\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\util.py:238: convert_variables_to_constants (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Utente\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\graph_util_impl.py:270: extract_sub_graph (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 6 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 6 variables to const ops.
```

It says that the input_example_tensor's shape is a string type.

for the model conversion i used this code

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(estimator_path)
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
converter.allow_custom_ops=True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

i have tried to convert in other way but i always get an error.
i have also tried to convert another premade estimator model (DNNClassifier), the iris classifier in example on tensorflow and the result are the same.
this is the tutorial on tensorflow.org
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/premade

the next step will be run this model on android, but the input tensor should be a float type.
im new in tensorflow and i dont know how to continue

Comment: Hi @tinooox, have you found a solution to this problem? does TFlite even support tf.string inputs? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: nope, tflite does not suppor the DNNClassifier yet, i had create my own NN